# PHP the selection cannot be run on any server

Tags: php

I have windows 10 as OS and downloaded eclipse IDE JAVA EE for developers , PHP from its official website and Apache Tomcat 8.0 . The latter is working fine in eclipse . So I made a new PHP project and a PHP file newfile.php . When I tried to run it , it failed . This is  what I did and how it failed:

1-

[image]

2-

[image]

3-

[image]

I searched in google for a help but I could not find . Moreover , I looked in Stack overflow in the **Similar questions** section  for solutions to **THIS SELECTION CANNOT BE RUN ON ANY SERVER** error for PHP but I could not find a solution that helps me . The suggested solutions were about JAVA not PHP . Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Try the `PHP Web Application` option instead. If that doesn't work, a little more config may be needed.

Comment: There's no need to `echo` with `phpinfo()`. It will send the output anyway.

Comment: But I want to run the newfile.php on Apache Tomcat Server not on the PHP Web Application